# How to create this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that allows me to know the estimated time of the flights with Spain as destination (the incoming airport is in Spain). And I have the following tables:

```
FLIGHT_PLAN(plan_number NUMBER, outgoing_airport NUMBER, estimated_flight_time NUMBER, incoming_airport NUMBER);

AIRPORT (code NUMBER, name VARCHAR(20), city_code NUMBER);

CITY (code NUMBER,name VARCHAR(20),country_code NUMBER);

COUNTRY (code NUMBER, name VARCHAR(20));
```

How can I go through this? How can I chain the `incomming_airport` field in `FLIGHT_PLAN` with code in `AIRPORT` and then code in `CITY` and code in `COUNTRY`?

Should I use foreign keys or what?

Comment: would be hard to estimate a time of flight given there is no information from the schema that you have provided that contains ANY interval information or even kms to derive from.

Answer (score 0):

You can link the tables up using

```
FROM COUNTRY C
inner join CITY I on I.country_code = C.code
inner join AIRPORT A on A.city_code = I.code
inner join FLIGHT_PLAN F on F.incoming_airport = A.code
WHERE C.name = 'Spain'
```

Note: Oracle is ase sensitive so watch the spelling of Spain, or use

```
WHERE UPPER(C.name) = 'SPAIN'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT plan_number, 
       outgoing_airport, 
       incoming_airport,
       estimated_flight_time
FROM flight_plan 
WHERE incoming_airport IN (SELECT ap.code
                           FROM airport ap 
                             JOIN city ct ON ct.code = ap.city_code
                             JOIN country co ON co.code = ct.country_code
                           WHERE co.name = 'Spain')
```

If you know the code for spain, you can leave out the JOIN in the sub-select and directly add `WHERE ct.country_code = 42`

If you need the name and city of the airport in the result, you'll have to join the main query agains airport and city:

```
SELECT fp.plan_number, 
       fp.estimated_flight_time,
       fp.outgoing_airport, 
       out_ap.name as outgoing_airport_name,
       out_city.name as outgoing_city_name,
       fp.incoming_airport,
       in_ap.name as incoming_airport_name,
       in_city.name as incoming_city_name
FROM flight_plan fp 
  JOIN airport in_ap ON in_ap.code = fp.incoming_airport
  JOIN city in_city ON in_city.code = in_ap.city_code
  JOIN airport out_ap ON out_ap.code = fp.outgoing_airport
  JOIN city out_city ON out_city.code = out_ap.city_code
WHERE incoming_airport IN (SELECT ap.code
                           FROM airport ap 
                             JOIN city ct ON ct.code = ap.city_code
                             JOIN country co ON co.code = ct.country_code
                           WHERE co.name = 'Spain')
```

Comment: Why do you need a query in the `WHERE` clause, especially in the second case where you're doing two identical queries? Why not do it in a way that cyberkiwi has pointed out?

Comment: It was needed in the first example as that does not have a join in it. In the second example it's simply copy & paste lazyness. You are correct in the second example it would required to join the country table to the main query which is just as valid as using the sub-select. Probably a matter of taste